# How to make a word with (-) between not to be separated?

Tags: html, css

How to make a word ( consequatur-reprehenderit ) not to be seprated at the edge?
like this

[image]

Comment: @MatthiasThalmann this will however cause overflow issues. So overall this solution is inpracticable. `non-breaking hyphen` is the way to go.

Comment: @tacoshy thats true.